# AZ Cli get vm creator user name or email

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm trying to fetch the event initiated by i.e. email id of the user who created the vm using az cli.
I tried running

```
az monitor activity-log list -g "resgroupname" --resource-id "my-res-id"
```

but it lists me all the vm details.
I'm trying to list the event of one vm by passing the resource id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `query` filter to the above cmdlet in order to the pull the user name (Caller) who initiated the create vm operation from the activity logs.

```
 az monitor activity-log  list -g <resourceGroupName> --resource-id <VMResourceId> --query "[?contains(operationName.value,'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write')].{name:operationName.value,caller:caller,createdtime:submissionTimestamp}" -o table
```

I have tested the above cmdlet in my local environment(cloud shell), by creating a log analytics workspace and projecting the activity logs of the resource group to that log analytics workspace.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: In caller I get some hashid ("6xxxxxxx-d0c3-4156-xxxx-6ce239xxxxxx")

Comment: @Aditya try checking that hashid belongs to any of the serviceprincipal/appregistration object id. if the VM got created using the ServicePrincipal then the respective object Id of that service principal get registered in the caller field.